# List button to be used in detail page button

Tags: custom-button, visualforce, button, list-button, detail-page

I have a List Button on a custom object. I need to use that button in that object as detail page button. Please find the VF page that List button calls here.

Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Compliance_Incident_abv__c" recordSetVar="Incidents" extensions="CompIncidentListActionController" tabStyle="Compliance_Incident_abv__c">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Selected Incidents to Publish" id="Pb1">
            <apex:pageMessages />

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="inc"  rendered="{!SelectedSize > 0}">
                <apex:column value="{!inc.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Rep_abv__c}"/>                
                <apex:column value="{!inc.OwnerId}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!inc.CreatedDate}"/>                                
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Publish_Date_abv__c}"/>                 
                <apex:column value="{!inc.No_Of_Transactions_abv__c}"/> 
                <apex:column value="{!inc.Status_abv__c}"/>                               
            </apex:pageBlockTable>      
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!Publish}"  rendered="{!SelectedSize > 0}"/>
                    <apex:commandButton value="Back" action="{!cancel}"/>                    
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>                     
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought you might have been able to use it for both in spite of the use of `recordSetVar` but I guess not. I think the solution here will be to create an 'in the middle' Visualforce page that uses the `Compliance_Incident_abv__c` standard controller, and as part of an init action simply redirects to the existing page passing a single Id.

So the page would look something like:

```
<apex:page standardController="Compliance_Incident_abv__c" extensions="CompIncidentDetailActionController" tabStyle="Compliance_Incident_abv__c" action="{!doForward"}">
</apex:page>
```

With the new extension controller looking something like this:

```
public with sharing class CompIncidentDetailActionController
{
  private Id recordId;

  public CompIncidentDetailActionController(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
  {
    recordId = sc.getRecord().Id;
  }

  public PageReference doForward()
  {
    // Use the old page name here
    ApexPages.PageReference pr = Page.ExistingPage;
    pr.getParameters().put('Ids', recordId);
    pr.setRedirect(true);
    return pr; 
  }
}
```

**Note** This code is completely untested and has been written straight in the browser, so a few method names could be wrong, but it demonstrates the technique at any rate.

Comment: Can you please let me know what should be the page? Getting a bit confused!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, expanded the answer which should get you going!